# Missed values when creating a dictionary with two values

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I have two lists as follows.

```
count = (1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2)
bins = [[2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 5.0], [5.0, 6.0], [6.0, 7.0], [7.0, 8.0], [8.0, 9.0], [9.0, 10.0], [10.0, 11.0], [11.0, 12.0], [12.0]]
```

I tried to create a dictionary using following;

```
dictionary = dict(itertools.izip(count, bins))
```

And it gives me `{"0": [7.0, 8.0], "1": [10.0, 11.0], "2": [11.0, 12.0]}`

It gives only the unique key values only but I need to get the all the pairs as below.

```
{"0": [3.0, 4.0],"0": [4.0, 5.0],"0": [6.0, 7.0],"0": [7.0, 8.0], "1": [2.0, 3.0],"1": [8.0, 9.0], "1": [9.0, 10.0], "1": [10.0, 11.0], "2": [6.0, 7.0] ,"2": [11.0, 12.0]}
```

or interchange of keys and values in the above dictionary is acceptable.(because keys should be unique)
How can I do that?

Comment: You can't use a `list` as a key as they are mutable. Using a `tuple` would work.

Comment: If an interchange is acceptable, could you tell us what you are really trying to do? This looks like XY problem. On a related note, what is wrong with just `itertools.izip(count, lst)`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I need to create a Json using these two lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a `list` as a key to a dictionary as it is mutable.

You could convert the `list` to a `tuple`:

```
>>> count = (1, 0, 0, 2, 0)
>>> bins = [[2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 5.0], [5.0, 6.0], [6.0, 7.0], [7.0, 8.0]]

>>> {tuple(key): value for (key, value) in zip(bins, count)}
{(4.0, 5.0): 0,
 (3.0, 4.0): 0,
 (5.0, 6.0): 2,
 (2.0, 3.0): 1,
 (6.0, 7.0): 0}
```

If you want to serialise to `json`, the keys need to be strings. You could convert the bins to strings instead:

```
>>> {str(key): value for (key, value) in zip(bins, count)}
{'[2.0, 3.0]': 1, '[4.0, 5.0]': 0, '[6.0, 7.0]': 0, '[5.0, 6.0]': 2, '[3.0, 4.0]': 0}

>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(_)
'{"[2.0, 3.0]": 1, "[4.0, 5.0]": 0, "[6.0, 7.0]": 0, "[5.0, 6.0]": 2, "[3.0, 4.0]": 0}'
```

Alternatively, just serialise the pairs, and make the dictionary on the receiving end:

```
>>> zip(bins, count)
[([2.0, 3.0], 1), ([3.0, 4.0], 0), ([4.0, 5.0], 0), ([5.0, 6.0], 2), ([6.0, 7.0], 0)]

>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(_)
'[[[2.0, 3.0], 1], [[3.0, 4.0], 0], [[4.0, 5.0], 0], [[5.0, 6.0], 2], [[6.0, 7.0], 0]]'
```

Comment: @ManuraOmal That's a different question. Short answer, yes, try it. If it doesn't work, search.

Comment: @ManuraOmal I've not used `json` from python before. I've just tried and the keys need to be strings. I'll update the answer so you have strings as keys instead of tuples

Answer (score 2):

`{"0": [3.0, 4.0],"0": [4.0, 5.0]}` is not a valid dictionary, as the keys in a dictionary have to be unique. If you really want the entries in `count` to be your keys, the best thing I can think of is to make a `list` of values for each key:

```
count = (1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2)
bins = [[2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 5.0], [5.0, 6.0], [6.0, 7.0], [7.0, 8.0], [8.0, 9.0], [9.0, 10.0], [10.0, 11.0], [11.0, 12.0], [12.0]]
answer = {}
for c, b in zip(count, bins):
    if c not in answer: answer[c] = []
    answer[c].append(b)
```

Comment: Result I got was - `{0: [<built-in function bin>, <built-in function bin>, <built-in function bin>, <built-in function bin>], 1: [<built-in function bin>, <built-in function bin>, <built-in function bin>, <built-in function bin>], 2: [<built-in function bin>, <built-in function bin>]}`

Comment: @ManuraOmal: oops! sorry about that typo. It's fixed now

Comment: Thank you very much. It gives not the expected but I can manage with your answer